# Firebase dynamic linking is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

[image]

When I send an invitation using firebase app invites, and when I open the link from desktop browser it redirects to play store instead of my website that I specified in deep linking. Above is the picture of debug page. If I click 'Web Link' from above debug page then it is working fine.

I also set up the SHA1, but still I am getting above warnings: Android app 'com.google.firebase.quickstart.invites' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app.

Can anybody help me to resolve the issue please!

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 is different from SHA1, and is used for the [Digital Asset Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#web-assoc) file under the hood. You should be able to get your SHA256 from the keytool just as you did with SHA1, and add that to the app in your Firebase project.

Comment: Barker Does it resolved the problem of opening link from desktop browser and redirect to my website instead of app ? I am sure that it will definitely resolve the warning message but not sure about my first redirection issue.

Comment: I added SHA256 but still if I open the link from desktop browser, it redirects to the play store instead of my website specified in firebase console.